# How can I preserve refrigerated cashew / almond milk by at least 2 months?

Tags: storage-lifetime, food-preservation, milk, vegan

How can I preserve refrigerated cashew / almond milk by at least 2 months?

I tried citric acid, but a very bad taste and smell resulted.

Does anyone know what can i use naturally to prolong the life when i make this natural vegan milk for my family?

Comment: Especially, don't add acid to any "milk", plant based or otherwise, unless your intent is to curdle it. Most nondairy milks will readily do that just as dairy does.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: [you can freeze it](http://www.canyoufreezethis.com/can-you-freeze-almond-milk/). Nut milks, especially homemade versions, can be frozen successfully. It doesn't seem to be a recommended practice according to commercial producers, but I would guess that's more to do with the emulsifiers and thickeners (typically [lecithin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecithin) or [xanthan gum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthan_gum)) used to improve the texture of commercially produced nut milks.

Assuming your freezer is properly set, [this will remain safe for as long as it's kept frozen](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/21069/25), although you might notice a decline in quality after extended storage.

The freezing and thawing can cause the nut milk to separate unevenly (making for a less pleasant texture) but [this site](http://veganinthekitchen.com/2011/06/02/how-to-freeze-and-defrost-almond-milk/) suggests a quick run through the blender to help re-emulsify the milk after thawing.